# Relative layout is not varying wrt its content

Tags: android, android-layout

I have written This code but I am facing problem as the relative layout height is not wrapping the content please help me regarding this
I wanted the coloured layout so i have done layout inside layout but the height didnt change after adding the buttos and text boxes
If i give height manually its done but I want it to vary as per content

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/Background"
    tools:context=".JewelInfo" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/HeadIm1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/Untitled"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/HeadIm2"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HeadIm1"
    android:background="@drawable/myj"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBelow="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HeadIm1"
    android:background="@drawable/menu"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="JEWELLERY DETAILS"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@drawable/Background" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Info"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
            android:text="Fill in the details about gold jewellery that you would like accessed &amp; Find out the current market value"
            android:textColor="#CFB52B" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/Info"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menubar" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/Jtype"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JName"
                android:layout_below="@+id/JName"
                android:background="@drawable/Black"
                android:text="Jewellery Type"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/weight"
                android:layout_width="95dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Jtype"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Jtype"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/JName"
                android:background="@drawable/Black"
                android:hint="Karat"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/browse"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:hint="Browse Image"
                    android:textSize="20dp" 
                    android:background="@drawable/Black" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/JWeight"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignBelow="@+id/browse"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Jtype"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/Jtype"
                    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                    android:layout_toRightof="@id/browse"
                    android:background="@drawable/Black"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Enter Gold Weight (gms)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp" />


              <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/JName"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/browse"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                    android:layout_toRightof="@id/browse"
                    android:background="@drawable/Black"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Jewellery Name"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />
                      <requestFocus />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just add

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

to TextView "info". This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @+id instead of @id while placing view in respect to each other

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/Background"
    tools:context=".JewelInfo" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/HeadIm1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/Untitled" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/HeadIm2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBelow="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HeadIm1"
        android:background="@drawable/myj"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/HeadIm1"
        android:background="@drawable/menu"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="JEWELLERY DETAILS"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="@drawable/Background" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Info"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
                android:text="Fill in the details about gold jewellery that you would like accessed &amp; Find out the current market value"
                android:textColor="#CFB52B" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Info"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/menubar" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/Jtype"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JName"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/JName"
                    android:background="@drawable/Black"
                    android:text="Jewellery Type"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/weight"
                    android:layout_width="95dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Jtype"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Jtype"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/JName"
                    android:background="@drawable/Black"
                    android:hint="Karat"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/browse"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/Black"
                    android:hint="Browse Image"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/JWeight"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignBelow="@+id/browse"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Jtype"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/Jtype"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                    android:layout_toRightof="@+id/browse"
                    android:background="@drawable/Black"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Enter Gold Weight (gms)"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/JName"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/browse"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_toRightof="@+id/browse"
                    android:background="@drawable/Black"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Jewellery Name"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <requestFocus />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have used @+id everywhere this is not helping

Comment: Please post your exact requirement. your Layout contains drawable views i am not able to figure out your exact requirement.

Comment: I am doing this Please view the link
http://cdn7.staztic.com/app/a/2256/2256036/muthoot-fincorp-my-jewel-box-4103-1-s-307x512.jpg

Comment: Have you made this layout or not ?

Comment: I have made this layout

Answer (score 0):

You are using ScrollView. You need to hardcode its height so that the content can scroll inside that specific height. If you say wrap_content then basically it will expand to fill all the content w/o giving option to you to scroll.

Also, if you want then you can set the height of ScrollView dynamically at run time by:-

```
sv = (ScrollView) findViewByID(R.id.scrollView1);

sv.getLayoutParams().height = x;
sv.getLayoutParams().width = x;                //just for information, you don't need it

sv.setLayoutParams(sv.getLayoutParams);
```

Using this code, you can set the height and width of the ScrollView. Setting height less than the total height required by views inside ScrollView will make it scrollable.

Also, you can get the size of screen and then set size of ScrollView accordingly:-

For  API<13

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
int screenHeight = display.getHeight(); //not required, just to inform

int x = (int) screenWidth/10;      //replace 10 by scaling factor

sv = (ScrollView) findViewByID(R.id.scrollView1);

sv.getLayoutParams().height = x;
sv.getLayoutParams().width = x;    //just for information, you don't need it

sv.setLayoutParams(sv.getLayoutParams);
```

For API>=13

```
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int screenWidth = size.x;
int screenHeight = size.y;         //not required, just for info

int x = (int) screenWidth/10; //replace 10 by scaling factor
sv = (ScrollView) findViewByID(R.id.scrollView1);

sv.getLayoutParams().height = x;
sv.getLayoutParams().width = x;     //just for information, you don't need it

sv.setLayoutParams(sv.getLayoutParams);
```

to check for API level at runtime, use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {

         //<code> if API>=13 (HONEYCOMB_MR2 is API 13)
}

else {

         //<code> if API<13
}
```

Hope it helps.
Happy Programming :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@drawable/Background"
              tools:context=".JewelInfo" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/HeadIm1"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/Untitled"/>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/HeadIm2"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/myj"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="JEWELLERY DETAILS"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
                android:background="@drawable/menu"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/Background"
            android:layout_weight="1">


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Fill in the details about gold jewellery that you would like accessed &amp; Find out the current market value"
                    android:textColor="#CFB52B" />

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/menubar">

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/browse"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:hint="Browse Image"
                        android:background="@drawable/Black"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                    <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/JName"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Jewellery Name"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:background="@drawable/Black"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <Spinner
                                android:id="@+id/Jtype"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Jewellery Type"
                                android:background="@drawable/Black"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:textSize="18dp" />

                        <Spinner
                                android:id="@+id/weight"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:hint="Karat"
                                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                android:background="@drawable/Black"
                                android:background="@drawable/Black"
                                android:textSize="18dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/JWeight"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Enter Gold Weight (gms)"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="16dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```